# AWS CloudFormation conditional template validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I have a template to create a CloudFormation with DynamoDB and DAX for multiple regions, for example, us-east-1 and ap-southeast-1.
While working for us-east-1, this template would not work for ap-southeast-1 since DAX is not yet available for that region.

I expected that this could be done using `Conditions`, so that for one region (us-east-1) I would have both DynamoDB and DAX and for another one (ap-southeast-1) - only DynamoDB:

```
Conditions: 
  isDAXAvailable: !Not [!Equals [ !Ref "AWS::Region", ap-southeast-1 ]]

Resources:
  DynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
    .....

  DaxCluster:
    Type: AWS::DAX::Cluster
    Condition: isDAXAvailable
    Properties:
    .....
```

But unfortunately I receive an error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate
>   operation: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types:
>   [AWS::DAX::Cluster]

Is it possible to configure such template anyhow or a separate one should be created?

Comment: For anyone with the same problem: unfortunately, I could not find any other solution but to create a separate template for that other region.

Answer (score 1):

Template validation is done against the resources available in a region. Since DAX is not currently available in ap-southeast-1, the *AWS::DAX::Cluster* resource will fail validation there. I have a couple of suggestions for how to make this work:

- Preprocess your template to strip out the DAX resources in not-currently-supported regions
- Split your template into three separate templates, which I’ll call *DAX*, *NoDAX*, and *Other*:

  - In regions that support DAX, create a stack with the *DAX* template that includes your cluster, and export the cluster’s name as the value of *ClusterName*.
  - In regions that don’t support DAX, create a stack with the *NoDAX* template, and export *none* as the value of *ClusterName*. Since every template needs a resource, include an *AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle*  as this template’s only resource.
  - In all regions, create a stack with *Other* template that imports *DaxClusterName*, and creates a conditional based on `Fn:Equals:  [“DaxClusterName”, “none”]`. Then use the conditional to determine whether the resources in this template can depend on the cluster.

Comment: DAX is now available in ap-southeast-1, so if that was the only region causing you problems, it shouldn't be anymore.

Comment: yeah, but for some other services it will still be an issue actually

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, there is a workaround of adding a transform like [`Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html) to your template**

While this might require adding a `CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND` capability, ["there is no charge incurred when using this transform"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-aws-serverless.html) and it shouldn't affect your template if you don't have any `AWS::Serverless` resources, and you should already be using this transform if you do have [`AWS::Serverless` resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-resources-and-properties.html)